# jquerymobile set title for native select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-select

Is it possible to set title to the select menu with `data-native-menu="true"` to show up on top of it? Something which describes what's that list for?

Comment: `placeholder` works only for `native-menu=false`.

Comment: Is there any modification or tweaks to pass the title/placeholder to the native menu?

Comment: native menu is a normal dropdown list, you can place an option on top with no value. It somehow acts as a place holder.